# In Snowplow, is it a compulsory to use DynamoDB in stream enrich process?

Tags: snowplow

I trying to develop a working example of Snowplow click tracking. I have to setup enrichment process to enrich raw data on Kinesis stream. But, when I am running JAR file, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager - Failed to get table status for SnowplowEnrich-${enrich.streams.in.raw}
```

Is DynamoDB a necessity for enrichment process?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this question ?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I found out that underlying KCL library uses DynamoDB to maintain application state, like no. of records processed and all. So, if you are using Kinesis, then you have to use KCL, which in turn uses DynamoDB. There is no escaping it.

Comment: Cool. I found that too. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Exactly the question I am asking. Seems like we have to use DynamoDB no matter what to use Stream enrich.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, in batch mode DynamoDB is not necessary for enrichment process, DynamoDB is used in the *RDB Shredder*.

Which release are (were) you trying to install. For a PoC you can use [Snowplow Mini](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-mini/wiki/Usage-guide#overview)

Snowplow community is active in [discourse.snowplowanalytics.com](http://discourse.snowplowanalytics.com)

Comment: I think he's asking for Stream enrichment mode. For batch mode, we can skip even skip DB or use postgre/redshift